# Typescript - accept keyof child class on function in base class

Tags: typescript

I have a function on my base class that takes the name of a property to watch:

```
class Parent {
    listenTo(prop: keyof this);
}
```

I then have a child class, that I want to watch one of its own properties

```
class Child extends Parent {
    foo = 3;
    constructor() {
        this.listenTo('foo');
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.  It complains that 'foo' isn't one of the valid keys, and then lists only the keys from Parent, not child.  Is there any to get the function declaration in Parent to look at the actual type, and not just itself?

Answer (score 1):

Testing it now in playground seems to work, but you'll need a `super` call:

```
class Parent {
    listenTo(prop: keyof this) {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
    foo = 3;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.listenTo('foo'); // ok
        this.listenTo('foo2'); // error
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGn6IAlhGqgCoD2AFAA4IU0Bc0A1kgJ4UBm0aAFsQCUWAL7Yx2UJBgBhASAAm0JAA9SKBTHjJ0WXPi4UK0ALzQAzAG59eYBRQkEAV2BoKCKsJz4f0CE5okD0FrX3x+YgA6IhJyagByQwp4kOgAejToChYbXwiIaOJ1SipEowAmFMt0zKD6BFyxESA)

Make sure typescript version is updated